# Which model should I use to fit my data ? ordinal and non-ordinal, not normal and not homoscedastic

Tags: r, logistic, model, ordered-logit, regression-strategies

Here is the kind of data I have:

I have two predictor variables:

1. discrete non-ordinal --> `c('a', 'b', 'c')`
2. discrete ordinal --> `c(10, 100, 200, 500)`

Response variable: Proportion of TRUE over a list of TRUE/FALSE. If the list is of length 3, my variable can take only 4 values. But not all my values come from the same list's length. And moreover the lists are globally long ! So it is discrete proportions but can take more than 100 values.

Here is an example (resp is a subset of my data):

```
pred_1 = rep(c(10, 20, 50, 100), 30)
pred_2 = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 40)
    
resp = c(0.08666667, 0.04000000, 0.13333333, 0.04666667, 0.50000000, 0.04000000, 0.02666667, 0.24666667, 0.15333333, 0.04000000, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.03333333,
    0.04000000, 0.26000000, 0.04000000, 0.04000000, 1.00000000, 0.28666667, 0.03333333, 0.06666667, 0.15333333, 0.06666667, 0.28000000, 0.35333333, 0.06000000,
    0.06000000, 0.05333333, 0.96666667, 0.06666667, 0.03333333, 0.22000000, 0.04666667, 0.04666667, 0.05333333, 0.05333333, 0.05333333, 0.08000000, 0.48666667,
    0.08666667, 0.02666667, 0.21333333, 0.45333333, 0.04666667, 0.36000000, 0.06666667, 0.04000000, 0.06000000, 0.07333333, 0.06000000, 0.04000000, 0.04666667,
    0.30000000, 0.08666667, 0.07333333, 0.06666667, 0.29333333, 0.36000000, 0.17333333, 0.04000000, 0.09333333, 0.11333333, 0.03333333, 0.08000000, 0.27333333,
    0.08666667, 0.03333333, 0.04000000, 0.02666667, 0.07333333, 0.07333333, 0.02000000, 0.02666667, 0.08000000, 0.07333333, 0.02666667, 0.06666667, 0.07333333,
    0.95333333, 0.05333333, 0.04000000, 0.11333333, 0.04000000, 0.07333333, 0.06666667, 0.05333333, 0.04000000, 0.04000000, 0.06000000, 0.12666667, 0.04666667,
    0.04000000, 0.21333333, 0.05333333, 0.97333333, 0.11333333, 0.02666667, 0.04000000, 0.03333333, 0.37333333, 0.25333333, 0.06000000, 0.06000000, 0.06000000,
    0.04666667, 0.26666667, 0.98000000, 0.02000000, 0.26000000, 0.06000000, 0.05333333, 0.28000000, 0.99333333, 0.04666667, 0.02666667, 0.04000000, 0.12666667,
    0.04666667, 0.18000000, 0.03333333)
```

my response variable is not at all normally distributed (kolmogorov-smirnow and shapiro test + visual checking with `qqplot()`) nor is the residuals of a linear model (`lm()`). Moreover the common assumption of homoscedasticity is not respected neither.

I've always asked a similar question but not as much accurate [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65388/which-model-should-i-use-logistic-regression).
Peter Flom has suggested that I use a ordinal logistic regression (`polr()`) but I might not have given him enough information (he did not know the number of levels for example). What do you think ? Which model would you suggest me ? Can I make a `polr()` with that much levels? When I do it I actually get this:

```r
Error message:
"Initial value "vmin" in not finite"

Notification message:
"glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred "
```

I'm struggling on this problem for quite a long time. All your contributions are more than welcome !

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not clear on what made you even entertain normality.  This looks like an ideal candidate for one of the ordinal cumulative probability models such as the proportional odds model.  In R you can use `polr`, or `orm` or `lrm` in the `rms` package.  A case study using `orm` is in Chapter 15 of my [Handouts](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CourseBios330).

Comment: Isn't the fact that I have more than 100 levels in my data a problem for using polr ? When I use polr on subset I don't get any error message but when I run it on the whole data set I get: "Initial value "vmin" in not finite" and this notification message: "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred "

Comment: @FrankHarrell In your handouts, you specify that `orm` is made to handle continuous variable. You also talk about log-log, complementary log-log, cauchit, probit and logit ! Knowing my variables (as described above (including the fact that I have more than 100 levels in my response variable)) which method would you suggest me ?

Comment: See the analysis of your data below for graphical assessments for the different distribution families.  Note that your $Y$ has 41 unique values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example using the R `rms` package `orm` function.  The three variables are defined in the original question above.  First we see which of 3 families yields the most parallelism.

```
require(rms)
row <- 0
for(gvar in list(pred_1, pred_2)) {
  row <- row + 1; col <- 0
  for(fun in list(qlogis, qnorm, function(y) -log(-log(y)))) {
    col <- col + 1
    print(Ecdf(~resp, groups=gvar, fun=fun,
               main=paste(c('pred_1','pred_2')[row],
                 c('logit','probit','log-log')[col])),
          split=c(col,row,3,2), more=row < 2 | col < 3)
  }
}
```

[image: Examining 3 families of ordinal models]

The proportional odds model does as well as any as judged by the logit transform of the ECDF.  Next fit the model, assess the global null hypothesis (P=0.175) and plot predicted means.  pred_1 is treated as linear.

```
f <- orm(resp ~ pred_1 + pred_2)
f

Logistic (Proportional Odds) Ordinal Regression Model

orm(formula = resp ~ pred_1 + pred_2)

                       Model Likelihood          Discrimination          Rank Discrim.    
                          Ratio Test                 Indexes                Indexes       
Obs             120    LR chi2      4.96    R2                  0.041    rho     0.183    
Unique Y         41    d.f.            3    g                   0.407                     
Median Y 0.06666667    Pr(> chi2) 0.1751    gr                  1.502                     
max |deriv|   2e-07    Score chi2   4.94    |Pr(Y>=median)-0.5| 0.077                     
                       Pr(> chi2) 0.1761                                                  

         Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
    pred_1   -0.0097 0.0046 -2.11  0.0346  
    pred_2=b  0.2822 0.3909  0.72  0.4703  
    pred_2=c  0.0734 0.3923  0.19  0.8517  

    anova(f)

                Wald Statistics          Response: resp 

 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 pred_1     4.47       1    0.0346
 pred_2     0.57       2    0.7531
 TOTAL      4.88       3    0.1809

    dd <- datadist(pred_1, pred_2); options(datadist='dd')
    bar <- Mean(f)
    plot(Predict(f, fun=bar), ylab='Predicted Mean')
```

[image: Predicted means from proportional odds model]

Plot predicted odds ratios.  For the numeric predictor, use inter-quartile-range odds ratio.

```
plot(summary(f), log=TRUE)
```

[image: Estimated odds ratios]

Comment: I can't get a summary from `f`: `Error in summary.rms(f) : adjustment values not defined here or with datadist for pred_1 pred_2`. I'm using rms 4.4-0.

Comment: Please fully read the documentation before trying to code.  You'll need to run the `datadist` function and define the name of the object holding that result using `options()` before running `summary` or plotting.

Comment: What exactly does Mean() do here and why is it appropriate for this outcome (heteroscedastic and nonormal)?

Comment: Mean uses the $\hat{\beta}$'s and all the estimated intercepts (which forms the empirical or underlying distribution) to estimate $E(Y|X)$.  It does so by computing Prob($Y=y_{j}$) for all $j$, multiplying by $y_{j}$, and adding them up.  Heteroscedasticity and non-normality are handled in estimating intercept and $\beta$.  $Y$ must be interval scaled for the mean to be meaningful, and the mean _may_ be meaningful for non-normal non-heterosc. $Y$.

Answer (score 3):

For regular (OLS) regression your response variable does *not* have to be normally distributed. The model assumes that the *residuals* from your model are normally distributed. You can first run regular regression and check the residuals, e.g.

```
m1 <- lm(resp~pred1 + pred2)
plot(m1)
```

This might be "good enough" but technically, since the response variable is bounded, it isn't quite right.

One method is to transform the response, e.g. by the arcsine transformation. Given that you don't have the data that made up the proportions, you can try:

```
library(scales)
transresp <- asn_tras(resp)
```

see [this page](http://rfd.uoregon.edu/files/rfd/StatisticalResources/arcsin.txt) for more on this method.

Another idea would be beta regression, which allows for a bounded response. `R` has a `betareg` package.

Comment: Yes, I tried several transformation but none of them succeded to give me something that looks normal (when looking at the residuals). Can a beta regression deal with values that equal 0 or 1 ? Thnks again !

Comment: But maybe the ordinal logistic regression that you suggested would be fine. Can I make an ordinal ogistic regression if I have more than 100 levels in the response variable ? I get an error message but maybe it is only a issue of programmation and not of statistics

Comment: That's indeed what I was affraid of. So what solution do I have left ? residuals won't never be normally distributed (homoscedasticity is not respected neither). Beta regression cannot deal with 0 and 1 (if I'm not mistaken ?)...So what could I use in order to know whether pred1 or pred2 or both or the interaction has an effect on resp ? many thnks !

Comment: You need no ties in $Y$ to use an ordinal model, as described in my case study.  You can have $n-1$ intercepts for $n$ observations.  The effective number of parameters estimated is close to 1 because of the ordering restriction on the intercepts.

Comment: I don't totally understand your explaination but basically you are saying that I can run a polr() with no fear? When I do that I get an error message. I reported my error message in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839292/polr-ordinal-logistic-regression-in-r) where they say that the problem is the high number of levels.

Comment: Frank is right; you have 109 intercepts and 1 effect. My other comment was incorrect. But I still think 109 levels is stretching things.

Comment: 109 levels presents no problem at all other than computational.  Instead of `polr` use the R `rms` package `orm` function which is made to handle thousands of intercepts efficiently.