# What is the correct test to use for a categorial dependent variable and an ordinal independent variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ordinal-data

I am trying to figure out if there exists a relation between the region someone lives in and their ranking of a website. The region variable is categorical, dependent, and spans 11 levels such as the Mountainous regions, Pacific Northwest, etc.

My ordinal independent variable is numbered from 1-9, with 9 being completely satisfied with the website, and 1 being completely dissatisfied.

The problem I am having here is that I am not sure which test to use with the ordinal independent variable. I would normally use the ANOVA but from my understanding I don't have an interval dependent variable here. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Why insist on that your independent variable is ordinal? Likert-type rating scales are often treated as interval, especially when being predictors. "Ordinal" predictors are always a problem, no satisfactory recipe exists.

Comment: You may replace the original variable by its ranks. This is one way to "cope" with ordinality - "since distribution on ordinal scale - if to see it as quatitative - is never known, replace it by uniform one".

Answer (score 0):

> My ordinal independent variable is numbered from 1-9, with 9 being completely satisfied with the website, and 1 being completely dissatisfied.

From your description this sounds more like your *dependent*, that is, response variable. Since this is ordinal, you can use a rank-based alternative to anova, that is the [Kruskal-Wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) test.  If you should happen to have more predictors (independent variables, covariables, ...) then ordinal regression is an extension, see

- [Kruskal-Wallis and Ordinal Logistic Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130209/kruskal-wallis-and-ordinal-logistic-regression)
- [Which model should I use to fit my data ? ordinal and non-ordinal, not normal and not homoscedastic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65548/which-model-should-i-use-to-fit-my-data-ordinal-and-non-ordinal-not-normal-an)