# Can I use change scores to analyze ordinal ratings?

Tags: ordinal-data, ancova, pre-post-comparison

I developed a re-coloring algorithm to make maps more accessible to the color vision impaired.  In order to test this algorithm, I created a questionnaire in which participants answered questions about maps with confusing colors (red and green) and re-colored maps.  This questionnaire format was based on the work of Cynthia Brewer.  Map order was random.

There were two groups of participants: 41 subjects with normal color vision (passed D15 panel arrangement test) and 41 subject with a color vision impairment (failed D15 test).  Each participant has three variables: questionnaire score using original maps (0 - 100), questionnaire score using re-colored maps (0 - 100) and color vision classification (0,1).

I have read about using gain scores with ANCOVA for this type of data.  I thought I could treat the original map scores as a pre-test and the re-colored map scores as a post test.  Unfortunately, these scores are not normally distributed.  Also, a participant can only improve a finite amount.  For example, if the participant scored 90% on the original map questionnaire, they can only improve at most 10% using the re-colored maps.  Is it valid to also use the pre-test score as a covariate?

I am using R to run this analysis.

Comment: Avoid change scores if possible.  The difference between two ordinal variables is no longer ordinal.  Consider ordinal regression on an absolute score as the dependent variable, e.g., proportional odds model.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Frank.  I apologize for my ignorance but I thought my questionnaire data are bounded continuous (moderator changed the title of my posting).  Questionnaire performance is measured from 0% to 100%... or should I just use the count of correctly answered questions as the score, instead?  The questionnaire score  distributions are severely skewed to the left (most normal vision participants scored 100% on both questionnaires) but change scores and potential change (100%- original map questionnaire score) can be normal with log transformation.

Comment: If the underlying values are skewed or you have any floor or ceiling effects, change scores can have a bizarre distribution.  That's why analyzing raw scores as ordinal is beneficial - this will handle any distribution plus floor and ceiling effects.

Comment: Thank you, Frank... I think I understand, now.  So the dependent variable would be the re-colored map questionnaire score (post-test), the factor would be color vision status and the covariate would be the original map questionnaire score (pre-test).  Which R package would you recommend?  I see there are several in the [R example repository](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/regressionOrdinal.html)

Comment: Hi, @FrankHarrell.  I found an example you provided in a [past post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65548/which-model-should-i-use-to-fit-my-data-ordinal-and-non-ordinal-not-normal-an) using the orm function from the rms package. I will use this example as a learning tool.  Thanks!