# How to choose a regression model?

Tags: regression

I have a distribution (of a dependent variable) like below. I have five independent variables. I want to fit an equation using regression. Which regression model I should choose? Or how should I choose a regression model?
[image]

Comment: This really isn't sufficient information to permit focused answers. "How to choose a regression model" is a huge subject that is too broad to be addressed here. The distribution of the dependent variable has little bearing on the choice of the model.  Have you [searched our site for ideas](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=choose+regression+model) yet?

Answer (score 1):

There are parametric regression models that may fit.  Elsewhere on this site is discussed ordinal regression, which is a semi-parametric model that *has* to fit the distribution of $Y$ for a given $X$ because it makes no distributional assumptions for any one set of $X$.

See for example [Which model should I use to fit my data ? ordinal and non-ordinal, not normal and not homoscedastic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65548/which-model-should-i-use-to-fit-my-data-ordinal-and-non-ordinal-not-normal-an/65668#65668)