# Analysis strategy for left skewed percentage response variable

Tags: regression, anova, data-transformation, percentage

I have a dataset that is made up of percentage values of DNA methylation at a number of loci and we are looking to model the relationship with a) a treatment and b) a genomic annotation.
The histogram of the data shows a left skewed data set, and as a percentage it obviously has an upper bound of 100.
[image]

The treatment predictor is binary (Y/N) and the annotation predictor can take 4 values.

```
#As I say above, we are trying to model
methylation~treatment+annotation+annotation:methylation
```

Given there are 0s and the data is a percentage I have tried arcsine and folded root transformations followed by anova. Unsurprisingly, these have had little effect on the tails of the residuals in the `qqplot`. There is no missing data.
So, are there any other potential transformations here or do I need to take a generalized linear model approach?

Comment: Is this counted percentages, that is, do you know numerator and denominator separately?

Comment: A semiparametric ordinal regression model is worth entertaining.

Comment: The answer by @FrankHarrell [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65548/which-model-should-i-use-to-fit-my-data-ordinal-and-non-ordinal-not-normal-an) looks a good guide